# Настройка Apache2 на Astra Linux

Tags: apache2, аутентификация, astra-linux

Всем привет!
Ситуация такова: есть Astra, на которой работает Apache2.2.22.

Но при попытке получение стартовой странички с "It works!" мне возвращается Internal Server Error.

Проверяю /var/log/apache2/error.log и вижу там такую ошибку:

> [crit] [client 192.168.0.39] configuration error:  couldn't perform authentication. AuthType not set!: /

Похоже, что необходимо указать AuthType. Странно, хотя [здесь](http://astra-linux.com/wiki/index.php/Apache2) написано минимальное содержимое файлов с конфигурациями виртуальных хостов и AuthType я там не нашёл.

Мне аутентификация не нужна. Потому я добавляю в /etc/apache2/sites-available/default AuthType None.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            AuthType None
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            AuthType None
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Перезапускаю apache, и снова захожу на страничку. Снова в ответ получаю 500, но теперь в логе другая ошибка:

> [crit] [client 192.168.0.39] configuration error:  couldn't check user.  Check your authn provider!: /

Тогда я посмотрел [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641646/how-to-accomplish-authtype-none-in-apache-2-2) и добавил Satisfy Any и Allow from all в обе секции. Результатом стала новая ошибка при попытке получения странички:

> [error] [client 192.168.0.39] Authentication not configured

Может кто-нибудь подсказать, как можно отключить аутентификацию?

P.S. Ещё я пробовал скормить дефолтные конфиги с debian 7. Результаты те же.

Comment: https://entnet.ru/server/puppet/nastrojka-apache.html Пример настройки без аутентификации.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Веб-сервер Apache2 в ОС Astra Linux Special Edition работает только с принудительной аутентификацией. Информация по настройке Apache2 доступна в документе "Руководство администратора. Часть 1 РУСБ.10015-01 95 01-1", пункт "12. ЗАЩИЩЕННЫЙ КОМПЛЕКС ПРОГРАММ ГИПЕРТЕКСТОВОЙ ОБРАБОТКИ ДАННЫХ" и при необходимости пункт "6.10.3. Web-сервер Apache2".

Спасибо службе сопровождения.

Comment: [Настройка PAM авторизации в защищенном Apache](http://lab50.net/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-apache/)

Answer (score 4):

**Для версии 1.6:**

Отключить авторизацию можно, задав "AstraMode off" в /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.
При отключении авторизации Apache2 осуществляет все запросы только от одной системной учетной записи (по умолчанию www-data).
Часть 1 РУСБ.10015-01 95 01-1, пункт 6.2.

Comment: Дмитрий, а вы на какой версии Астры работали?

Comment: Astra Linux SE 1.6

Comment: Вероятно, уже многое изменилось. Мой вопрос касался версии 1.4, или даже 1.3.

Comment: Поправил ответ, может пригодится кому.

Answer (score 0):

**Для версии 1.6, 1.7, 4.7, 8.1**
Отключение авторизации можно задать в файле /etc/apache2/apache2.conf раскоментировав `#AstraMode on` и поменять на `AstraMode off` .

**Для версии 1.5 и более ранних**
работает только с принудительной аутентификацией через PAM, либо Kerberos и отключить аутентификацию невозможно.

ссылка на документацию: https://wiki.astralinux.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=36077643